# Node in linked-List with C language

Tags: c, linked-list

I start learning linked list,so my question may be stupid :p . I noticed that in all the exercices, they only take one data element in the node( as below : int data).So i am asking can we define multiple data elements in one node.Otherwise why not?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* nextptr;
};

struct node* BuildList()
{
  /* initialize node's pointers */
  struct node* head = NULL;
  struct node* second = NULL;
  struct node* third = NULL;
  /* allocate three nodes in the heap*/
  head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  /* setup first node */
  head->data = 1;
  head->nextptr = second;

  second->data = 2;
  second->nextptr = third;
  third->data =3;
  third->nextptr = NULL;

  return head;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it!

Comment: What happened when you tried to add another data member to `struct node`?

Comment: . o O ( another [list without a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54843225/3975177) :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `int` just make it easier for the examples. But in real life, the node will be something more useful. Example:

```
struct chair {
    int nr_or_legs;
    int weight_in_kg;
    int height_in_cm;
};

struct chair_node {
    struct chair data;
    struct chair_node* nextptr;
};
```

or just:

```
struct chair_node {
    int nr_or_legs;
    int weight_in_kg;
    int height_in_cm;
    struct chair_node* nextptr;
};
```